Convert table to CSV in Angular 17
I'm trying to add a download button to convert table in CSV format.
PS: Most of the StackOverflow answers regarding this topic are several years old.
Here's my Angular 17 table code in HTML which is displaying the data in table format:
<button (click)="exportcsv()" class="bnt btn-primary">Download</button>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table" id="htmlData">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">Mode</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-group-divider">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of income; let count = index;">
        <th scope="row">{{count +1}}</th>
        <td>{{item.date | date: "dd MMM, yyyy '@' hh:mm a"}}</td>
        <td>{{item.registration.RegistrationId}}</td>
        <td>{{(item.registration.fullName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.totalAmount}}</td>
        <td>{{item.paymentMode}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

This is my .TS code but it's throwing an error while compiling:
exportcsv(): void {
    let csv='';
    let table=document.getElementById("htmlData");
    let tr=table.children[0].children[0];
    for(let i=0;i<tr.children.length;i++)
      {
        csv+=tr.children[i].innerText+",";
      }
    csv=csv.substring(0,csv.length-1)+"\n";
    let tbody=table.children[1];
    for(let i=0;i<tbody.children.length;i++)
    {
        for(let j=0;j<tbody.children[i].children.length;j++)
        {
            csv+=tbody.children[i].children[j].innerText+",";
        }
        csv=csv.substring(0,csv.length-1)+"\n";
    }
    csv=csv.substring(0,csv.length-1)+"\n";
        let hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
        hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = 'data.csv';
        hiddenElement.click();
}

Error when compiling using ng serve:
Error: src/app/income.component.ts:74:12 - error TS18047: 'table' is possibly 'null'.
74     let tr=table.children[0].children[0];
              ~~~~~
Error: src/app/income.component.ts:77:29 - error TS2339: Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'Element'.
77         csv+=tr.children[i].innerText+",";
                               ~~~~~~~~~
Error: src/app/income.component.ts:80:15 - error TS18047: 'table' is possibly 'null'.
80     let tbody=table.children[1];
                 ~~~~~
Error: src/app/income.component.ts:85:48 - error TS2339: Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'Element'.
85             csv+=tbody.children[i].children[j].innerText+",";


Using document.getElementById() can be undefined.
You could try to use a template variable for example:
<table #htmlData> ... </table>
and in your component.ts use a signal query like:
myTable = viewChild.required("htmlData");
Then you could use this variable in your Method like this:
this.myTable().children[...]
The subsequent errors should then also disappear.

You can annotate the type after document.getElementById
I have also changed innerText to nodeValue
exportcsv(): void {
    let csv = '';
    const table = document.getElementById("htmlData") as HTMLTableElement;
    const tr = table.children[0].children[0];

    for(let i=0; i < tr.children.length; i++) {
        csv += tr.children[i].innerText+",";
    }

    csv = csv.substring(0,csv.length-1) + "\n";

    const tbody = table.children[1];
    for(let i = 0; i < tbody.children.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < tbody.children[i].children.length; j++) {
            csv += tbody.children[i].children[j].innerText+",";
        }

        csv = csv.substring(0,csv.length-1) + "\n";
    }
    csv = csv.substring(0,csv.length-1)+"\n";
    
    const hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'data.csv';
    hiddenElement.click();
}

